# Android app crash on MainActivity onCreate

Tags: android, crashlytics

I see in my crashlytics report that my android app crashes for some devices right on startup with the following crash details:

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f080141
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:283)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:845)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:691)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:307)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1017)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1010)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:985)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:234)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:220)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:233)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:152)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1024)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:988)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1150)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:709)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:547)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:485)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:775)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:197)
       at com.MyAppPackageName.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8176)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8143)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1330)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3744)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3938)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2291)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8309)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
```

now I cannot reproduce the crash because I do not know why it happens and in my phone it does not crash.

any ideas how can I find and fix the cause of it?
thanks

Comment: What is in `MyActivity.java` line 77?

Comment: @AleksG just `setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)`